# Can anyone explain why my Z-Index isn't working as expected?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to create a "sticky" navigation bar, however the content further down the page appears over the top of the navigation bar after scrolling. I've tried applying z-indexes to the navigation but not sure why it isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated!

HTML

```
        <!-- Start Header -->
    <header classs="parallax">
        <section id="stickynav">
            <div class="container-responsive">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        Content
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        Content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>
    <!-- End Header -->
    <!-- Start Main -->
    <section id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Main -->
```

CSS

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    background-image: url('../images/slider/accounting-banner.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 90%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 90%);
    color: #fff;
}
section#stickynav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 12%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
.stickystyle {
    background-color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    color: #000;
}
section#main {
    margin-top: -2.5%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

JS

```
<script>
    var sn = $("#stickynav");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            sn.addClass("stickystyle");
        } else {
            sn.removeClass("stickystyle");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: [I can't reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/xnk30eq5/). Please create a [functional example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate.

Comment: Give `header` a `z-index:1` instead, and you can leave out the `section#main {z-index:-1;}`. (Maybe your browser doesn't recognize negative z-index, I don't know

Comment: I created a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/j1bnLeaa/ that shows the issue (although it doesn't show the layout properly). I'm not sure whether it's a browser issue. I just tried to access the website on my macbook & it works on safari, however on windows it isn't displaying proper on Chrome/Opera.

Comment: Try taking the navigation bar out from the header tag. The navigation bar should be going over the header, not in it.

Comment: I want the navigation bar to overlap the header though, then when they scroll turn into a solid bar at the top. Is that possible if I move the navigation bar outside the header tag?

Comment: Ah, I've got it to work now. Moving the header outside worked! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your navigator outside of your header. Here is a snippet:

```
<!-- Start Header -->
    <header></header>
    <!-- End Header -->
<!-- Start Navigator -->
    <section id="stickynav">
            <div class="container-responsive">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        Content
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        Content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
<!-- End Navigator -->
```

Here is the css:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
   background-image: url('https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/TD1JOZO7IX.jpg');
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 90%);
   clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 90%);
   color: #fff;
}
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('../images/logo.png');
    height: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
section#stickynav {
    position: fixed;
  top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 12%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
.stickystyle {
    background-color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    color: #000;
}

section#main {
    margin-top: -2.5%;
}
```

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/MoMRGK) based on your fiddle.